# If string2 is a prefix for string1

Tags: python

```
def equiv(s1, s2):
   
    if s1 == "":
        return True
    elif s1[0] == s2[0]:
        return equiv(s1[1:], s2[1:])
    elif s1[0] != s2[0]:
        return equiv(s1, s2[1:])
    else:
        return False
```

The error I'm getting is that the string index is out of range

Comment: If `s1[0]` is not equal to `s2[0]`, wouldn't that mean you should return False?

Comment: Which line of code does it tell you is causing the error? Now, **look at that line of code**. What are the strings mentioned on that line? What index is being used for each string? Can you think of a value the string could have, that would make such an index fail?

Comment: Your function will get an error if `s2` is shorter than `s1`, because it will eventually recurse with `s2` being an empty string, and then `s2[0]` is out of range.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to trace through the logic, step by step, with an input that causes the error.

Comment: You'll never get to the `else:` line. If `s1[0] == s2[0]` is false, then `s1[0] != s2[0]` is true, so the `elif` will always be executed. So this function can never return `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Python startswith() function

```
>>> "apple".startswith("app")
True
```

but probably you are just learning recursion so here is the problem with the function. Either `s1[0] == s2[0]` will be true or `s1[0] != s2[0]` will be. (Something is always not equals to OR equals to). Return false will never happen. Because of this, it will just continue to remove letters from the beginning, until it reaches the end, and causes an error.

When I say remove 1 letter I am talking about `s1[1:]` because that basically is a new array starting at index 1 of previous array, so it basically removes 1 letter

If you start with `equiv("abz","abcd")` or something, the first time the function is run, `s1[0] == s2[0]` so it removes 1 letter from both strings and calls `equiv("bz","bcd")`. Then it does the same thing again and calls `equiv("z","cd")`. And now, `s1[0] != s2[0]` so according to your function, it would only remove a letter from `s2` so it calls `equiv("z","d")` and this time there are still not equal, so it removes another letter, and this time calls `equiv("z","")`. This is still not equal but when it tries to remove one letter, it doesn't work, and gives an error because there is no letter to remove.

You don't need to do anything if `s1[0] != s2[0]`, because that would mean that they don't start with the same letter.

For example, if you put do `equiv("bc","abcd")` it would print True, because it `s1[0] != s2[0]` will be true, and it will remove 1 letter from s2. Now it calls `equiv("bc","bcd")` which will be True.

So basically all you need for your function is

```
def equiv(s1, s2):

    if s1 == "":
        return True
    elif s1[0] == s2[0]:
        return equiv(s1[1:], s2[1:])
    elif s1[0] != s2[0]:
        return False
```

If the first letter don't equal, just return false because that means it's not a prefix.

tl;dr: if letters don't equal, it keeps removing one letter from `s2`, when it runs out of letters, it breaks. Solution is to just return false if `s1[0] != s2[0]`, because that means it's not equal